# Modifying width of input field in react day picker input

Tags: react-day-picker

Is it possible to change the default width of input field of DayPickerInput? If yes, then how can I achieve it? I am not sure if we can do this with overlayComponent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `inputProps` to add your props such as style to the `input` field. See docs: http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput#inputProps

For example:

```
<DayPickerInput inputProps={{ style: { width: 200 } }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing your own styles, but first check the stylesheets of day picker here - react-day-picker/lib/style.css and then modify accordingly.

Comment: I can for sure write my own custom style. but is there a way to pass that custom style as props to the DayPickerInput component? Or are you suggesting to override the whole style.css with a new css file?